# Toggleable sidebar navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am working on a site that needs a toggle-able sidebar navigation, and it needs to work like so:

[image]

At the moment, I have the left navbar set to "position: fixed", and then the content has a "padding-left" value of the navbar's width.
I have then used this code to create the transition:

```
.navbar {
    width: 95px;
    -webkit-transition: width 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: width 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: width 500ms ease;
    transition: width 500ms ease;
}

.toggle-navbar {
    width: 250px;
}

.content {
    padding-left: 95px;
    -webkit-transition: padding-left 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: padding-left 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: padding-left 500ms ease;
    transition: padding-left 500ms ease;
}

.toggle-content {
    padding-left: 250px;
}
```

The 'toggle-' classes are then added with `$(elem).toggleClass('toggle-class')`

Is there a better way to do this? Also is it possible to achieve this using css3 transitions that make use of hardware-acceleration (keeping the animation smooth on iOS devices)?

Comment: will u be using objective c ?

Comment: Whoops! Didn't mean to tag iPhone by itself. Fixed!

Comment: @Sneaksta because i can see all the problems you are going to have with this way already...may i suggest that instead of "pushing" the content div to the right, to make the nav bar to overlap the content?

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions as I am aware that my current solution is quite hacky. How would you propose I make the navbar overlap the content?